# Change Virtual Machine Tier for running / production server

Tags: azure

I have an A2 VM currently configured to be 'standard' virtual machine tier. Can I switch that over to the 'basic' tier while it is live? There is no auto-scaling or load-balancing. It's a 'stand-alone' machine running a simple website and database.

Will it go offline? Will data be lost? Will I need to rebuild / re-provision it?

... or, as I hope, will it just update the billing information.

Thanks :-)

Comment: According to the FAQ changing the size will trigger a restart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn763935.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the VM will be restarted so your website will suffer downtime.